# Plot bokeh MultiLine using different width

Tags: python, bokeh, multiline

I would like to use MultiLine with a list that provides the LineWidth, so that each edge in the graph is plotted with a different width. Below is a simplified example taken from the [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/multi_line.html) which throws an error. Is there a possibility to use MultiLine with different width? Or do you know a different way to plot a graph with different width?

```
    import networkx as nx

    from bokeh.io import show, output_file
    from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, HoverTool, TapTool, BoxSelectTool
    from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx
    from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
    import numpy as np

    G=nx.karate_club_graph()
    ewidth = [np.random.random() for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True)]

    plot = Plot(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
                x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1))
    plot.title.text = "Graph Interaction Demonstration"
    plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None), TapTool(), BoxSelectTool())

    graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.circular_layout, scale=1, center=(0,0))
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[0])

    #this works:
    #graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#CCCCCC", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=5)

    # this doesnt work:
    graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#CCCCCC", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=ewidth)


    plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

output_file("interactive_graphs.html")
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. For those who stumble about the same question here the solution. You can do it either with `set_edge_attributes` or by adding the property to the data source

```
graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data['edge_width'] = ...
```

below the code:

```
        import networkx as nx

        from bokeh.io import show
        from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, HoverTool, TapTool, BoxSelectTool
        from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx
        from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
        import numpy as np

        G=nx.karate_club_graph()

        #option 1    
        edge_attrs={}
        for  (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True):
            edge_attrs[(u, v)] = np.round(np.random.random() ,2)
        nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_attrs, "edge_width")
        ###

        plot = Plot(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
                    x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1))
        plot.title.text = "Graph Interaction Demonstration"
        plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None), TapTool(), BoxSelectTool())

        graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.circular_layout, scale=1, center=(0,0))
        # option 2    
        #graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data['edge_width']=[np.random.random() for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True)]
        ###
        graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[0])
        graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#CCCCCC", line_alpha=0.8, line_width="edge_width")

        plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

        show(plot)
```